# How to add dynamic webprojects to an EAR programmatically in Java?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I created a dynamic web project. I want to add this to an ear project. I want this EAR project to be created programmatically and add some additional facets to it and add dynamic web project to that EAR.

What i have done now is, created a web project and added below property to add that to an EAR project.

> iDataModel.setBooleanProperty(IWebFacetInstallDataModelProperties.ADD_TO_EAR
>   ,true);

This will create EAR with default settings. But i dont want this. I want to create EAR project and add some more IBM facets to it. so i created an EAR as below.

> IDataModel earModel =
>   DataModelFactory.createDataModel(new
>   EARFacetProjectCreationDataModelProvider());
>   earModel.setProperty(IFacetDataModelProperties.FACET_PROJECT_NAME,
>   projName);
>   earModel.getDefaultOperation().execute(
>   monitor, null);

with this i can add some additional facets to this EAR project. But i dont know how to add web project to this EAR.

Help me if anyone came across this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I got this worked finally. In this way, we can choose desire list of web and java projects to be added to a one or more EAR projects programmatically.

> public void createEARProject(IProject
>   iEARProj, IProject iWebProj,
>   IProgressMonitor monitor) throws
>   ExecutionException, CoreException{
>
> IProjectDescription earProjectDesription =
>   ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().newProjectDescription(iEARProj.getName());
>         iEARProj.create(earProjectDesription,
>   monitor);         iEARProj.open(monitor);
>
> final IFacetedProject
>   earFacetedProject =
>   ProjectFacetsManager.create(iEARProj,
>   true, monitor);       IActionDefinition
>   earInstallAction =
>   EARFacetUtils.EAR_14.getActionDefinition(Collections.singleton(EARFacetUtils.EAR_14),
>   IFacetedProject.Action.Type.INSTALL);
>         IDataModel earConfig = (IDataModel)
>   earInstallAction.createConfigObject(EARFacetUtils.EAR_14,
>   iEARProj.getName());
>
> earConfig.setProperty(IEarFacetInstallDataModelProperties.J2EE_PROJECTS_LIST,
>   Arrays.asList(new
>   IProject[]{iWebProj}));
>   earConfig.setProperty(IEarFacetInstallDataModelProperties.JAVA_PROJECT_LIST,
>   Collections.EMPTY_LIST);
>   earConfig.setBooleanProperty(IFacetDataModelProperties.SHOULD_EXECUTE,
>   Boolean.TRUE);
>
> IDataModel master =
>   DataModelFactory.createDataModel(new
>   EARFacetProjectCreationDataModelProvider());
>   master.setStringProperty(IFacetDataModelProperties.FACET_PROJECT_NAME,
>   earConfig.getStringProperty(IFacetDataModelProperties.FACET_PROJECT_NAME));
>   master.setProperty(IFacetProjectCreationDataModelProperties.FACET_DM_MAP,
>   Collections.singletonMap(EARFacetUtils.EAR_FACET.getId(),
>   earConfig));
>   master.setProperty(IFacetProjectCreationDataModelProperties.FACET_ACTION_MAP,
>   Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
>   master.setProperty(FacetProjectCreationDataModelProvider.REQUIRED_FACETS_COLLECTION,
>   Collections.singletonList(EARFacetUtils.EAR_FACET));
>
> earConfig.setProperty(FacetInstallDataModelProvider.MASTER_PROJECT_DM,
>   master);
>
> earFacetedProject.installProjectFacet(EARFacetUtils.EAR_14,
>   earConfig, monitor);
>   earFacetedProject.setFixedProjectFacets(Collections.singleton(EARFacetUtils.EAR_FACET));
>
> }

Hope this helps if anyone trying the way i tried.